# Infinite loop with setting time of sleep

Tags: python, loops, time, sleep

I want to set a sleep as a value from input, but it doesn't work:

```
import win32api, win32con, time
def jump(x,y):
    x0, y0 = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x0+x,y0+y))


t = int(input("type time of sleepin [s]: "))

while True:
    jump(10,10)
    time.sleep(t)
```

Comment: `while True` will run forever... you have to provide a way to break out of the loop.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? If I boil this down to `while True: print('hello'); sleep(t)` the `sleep` call works just fine

Comment: I know it will run forever but how to define intelval of action as input value?

Comment: Why does what you have written not work?

Comment: Ok, it works. The problem was with sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop (notice the name) executes *while* its condition is `True`:

```
while (condition):
    # Code
```

So putting `True` as condition, you will have a neverending loop.